# Calculate percentage of similar values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe `df`, with two columns : Script (with text) and Speaker

```
Script  Speaker
aze     Speaker 1 
art     Speaker 2
ghb     Speaker 3
jka     Speaker 1
tyc     Speaker 1
avv     Speaker 2 
bhj     Speaker 1
```

And I have the following list : `L = ['a','b','c']`

With the following code,

```
df = (df.set_index('Speaker')['Script'].str.findall('|'.join(L))
        .str.join('|')
        .str.get_dummies()
        .sum(level=0))
print (df)
```

I obtain this dataframe `df2` :

```
Speaker     a    b    c
Speaker 1   2    1    1
Speaker 2   2    0    0
Speaker 3   0    1    0
```

Which line can I add in my code to obtain, for each line of my dataframe `df2`, a percentage value of all lines spoken by speaker, in order to have the following dataframe `df3` :

```
Speaker     a    b    c
Speaker 1   50%  25%   25%
Speaker 2  100%    0   0
Speaker 3   0   100%   0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could divide by the `sum` along the first axis and then cast to string and add `%`:

```
out = (df.set_index('Speaker')['Script'].str.findall('|'.join(L))
         .str.join('|')
         .str.get_dummies()
         .sum(level=0))
```

---

```
(out/out.sum(0)[:,None]).mul(100).astype(int).astype(str).add('%')

            a     b    c
Speaker                  
Speaker1   50%   25%  25%
Speaker2  100%    0%   0%
Speaker3    0%  100%   0%
```

Answer (score 5):

Starting from your original dataframe, if you want % and not grouped sum of dummies , you can change the entire script like below:

```
m = df.set_index('Speaker')['Script'].str.findall('|'.join(L)) #creates a list of matches
m = m.explode().reset_index() #explode to a series 
final = pd.crosstab(m['Speaker'],m['Script'],normalize='index').mul(100) # percentage pivot
```

---

```
Script         a      b     c
Speaker                      
Speaker 1   50.0   25.0  25.0
Speaker 2  100.0    0.0   0.0
Speaker 3    0.0  100.0   0.0
```

If you dont want the percentage just use:

```
pd.crosstab(m['Speaker'],m['Script'])
```

---

```
Script     a  b  c
Speaker           
Speaker 1  2  1  1
Speaker 2  2  0  0
Speaker 3  0  1  0
```

Note: this uses pandas 0.25+ as version

Answer (score 3):

```
(df.set_index('Speaker')['Script'].str.extractall(f'({"|".join(L)})')
   .groupby('Speaker')[0].value_counts(normalize=True)
   .unstack(fill_value=0)
)
```

Output:

```
0            a     b     c
Speaker                   
Speaker 1  0.5  0.25  0.25
Speaker 2  1.0  0.00  0.00
Speaker 3  0.0  1.00  0.00
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the example you can try with the following line of code:

```
df = (df/df.sum(axis=1)[:, None]).mul(100).astype(int)
```

With the data you provide:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'a':[2,2,0],'b':[1,0,1],'c':[1,0,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = (df/df.sum(axis=1)[:, None]).mul(100).astype(int)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     a   b   c
0   50  25  25
1  100   0   0
2    0 100   0
```

Or, if you wish to add the '%' symbol:

```
df = (df / df.sum(axis=1)[:, None]).mul(100).astype(int).astype(str) + '%'
```

Output:

```
      a     b    c
0   50%   25%  25%
1  100%    0%   0%
2    0%  100%   0%
```